# How should I lock a wxMutex in one function and unlock it in another?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, wxwidgets, mutex

I'm supposed to implement my own logging class for use in a program with two threads, the main one and a joinable processing thread. I don't want either thread to use the logger while the other is using it, so I figured I'd use a wxMutex. The logger has to act like a C++ ostream with operator<<, except that a stream manipulator function (std::endl, for example) will indicate the end of the logger's output. I think I need a recursive mutex so that the same thread can continue outputting when the mutex is locked.

The problem (I think) is that the mutex doesn't get fully unlocked, so when the other thread tries to output to the logger, it deadlocks.

Is there something in my code that I'm missing?

```
class Logger{
  private:
    std::ostream* out;
    wxMutex* mut;
  ....
  public:
    template<class T>
    Logger& operator<<(T str){ // accept any type of input and lock outputting until finished
      if(out){
        if(mut->TryLock() == wxMUTEX_BUSY){ // if we didn't get lock
          mut->Lock(); // we block
        }
        if(out){
          (*out) << str;
          out->flush();
        }
        //mut->Unlock(); // leave locked until done outputting (use std::endl or similar)
      }
      return *this;
    }

    // accept stream manipulators and unlock stream output
    Logger& operator<<(std::ostream& (*pf) (std::ostream&)){
      if(out){
        if(mut->TryLock() == wxMUTEX_BUSY){
          mut->Lock();
        }
        (*out) << pf;
        out->flush();
        while(mut->Unlock()!= wxMUTEX_UNLOCKED);
      }
      return *this;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are worried about threading issues, you could instead make a macro that makes sure the mutex is acquired before the output and released after the output.

Something like:

```
#define LOG(logger, output) \
    do { logger.lock(); logger << output; logger.unlock(); } while (0)

Logger my_logger;
int some_integer = 5;
LOG(my_logger, "Hello world!" << some_integer << std::endl);
```

Comment: By the way, I would recommend that with this solution put the newline/flushing (i.e. the `<< std::endl` part) in the macro so it doesn't have to be done by the user of the macro.

Comment: Ah. I hadn't thought of using a macro to wrap my output like this. This is exactly what I needed. I forgot that you can use a macro argument like you did here with `output`, where it can take a whole expression and insert it like that. With this, I won't need to have to try to unlock somewhere else. I don't think I'll need a recursive mutex, either.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in wxWidgets 2.9 `wxLog` itself is MT-safe and you can have independent log targets for each thread so perhaps you could just use it instead of writing your own.

Second, using `TryLock()` is suspicious, if you want to be able to re-lock the mutex already belonging to the current thread, you should use `wxMUTEX_RECURSIVE` when creating the mutex and simply use `Lock()` nevertheless. However personally I believe that using recursive mutexes is a *bad* idea because it makes your MT-code less clear and more difficult to reason about and this is almost invariably catastrophic.

Finally, the whole idea of relying on someone to call `<< endl` is just wrong. It's too easy to forget to do it somewhere and leave the mutex locked preventing all the other threads from continuing. You absolutely should create a proxy object locking the mutex in its ctor and unlocking it in its dtor and use it to ensure that the mutex is always unlocked at the end of statement doing the logging. I think that by using this technique you should avoid the need for recursive mutexes too.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but it looks to me that you are trying to lock the mutex when it is in use already.

```
if(mut->TryLock() == wxMUTEX_BUSY) // if TryLock() returns wxMUTEX_BUSY another thread is using it.
{
    mut->Lock(); // A dead lock situation could be detected here because Lock() also returns an error code.
}
```

TryLock() usually attempts to acquire the mutex without blocking. So, if the mutex is already busy on that call, it means that another thread is using it.

You could have a look to [this link from wxMutex](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxmutex.html) which explains how each functions works. Their function returns values, so you could use that to see what's going wrong in your program.

See the doc from their website below.

> **wxMutex::Lock**
>
> **wxMutexError Lock()**
>
> Locks the mutex object.
>
> Return value
>
> One of:
>
> **wxMUTEX_NO_ERROR**   There was no error.
>
> **wxMUTEX_DEAD_LOCK**  A deadlock situation was detected.

Comment: I do want to block if one thread tries to output while another is in the process of logging. I probably don't really need the TryLock() checks.